# При попытке скачать файл с собственного реализованного http-сервера на Jave бразер дико лагает и скорость низкая

Tags: java, http, http-server

Собственно вот такой вот код:

```
if(Files.exists(Path.of(HttpServer.directory+path)) && ! Files.isDirectory(Path.of(HttpServer.directory+path))) {
    // System.out.println("File exists: "+HttpServer.directory+path);
    File f = new File(HttpServer.directory+path);
    String header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type: file/file\nContent-Length: " + f.length() + "\nConnection: close\n\n";
    InputStream fileContent = new FileInputStream(f);
    out.write(header.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    while (fileContent.available() > 0)
        out.write(fileContent.read());
    out.flush();
}
```

`HttpServer.directory` - содержит в себе путь до директории, в которой будет происходить хостинг файлов на http-сервере, она указывается в аргументах запуска, в моем случае это `C:/PFB/Server`, а `path` - содержит в себе URI из http-запроса GET.

HttpServer запущен на 8080 порте.
Итак, у меня на ПК содержится файл по пути `C:/PFB/Server/asd.exe` весом 578 мб, а так же по пути `C:/PFB/Server` у меня находится еще парочка мелких файлов.

Я захожу в браузер, пытаюсь сначала скачать эту парочку файлов, всё успешно, но когда я ввожу http://localhost:8080/asd.exe, то есть хочу скачать большой файл, у меня браузер начинает дико виснуть, скорость загрузки 20 кб/с, при попытке что-то делать браузер не отвечает.

Может, файл нельзя закидывать целиком в HTTP-ответ? Может, нужно создать несколько TCP соединений?

Нигде данной информации я не нашел.
В чём заключается проблема, и есть ли по этому поводу статьи в интернете?

Comment: Думаю... что повисание исключительно из-за localhost. Когда связь идет с серваком - то все идет через сокет определенными кусками. Касательно разбития на части, есть 2способа разбития.  TCP пакеты и так  должны биться, разбить принудительно можно только переписав на чистые сокеты, один send = один пакет. Http протокол не очень сложно реализовать на чистых сокетах. Второй вариант - скачивание частями. В http протоколе есть headers которые позволяют бить на части (один httpзапрос=один пакет), если руцями это писать - то сложно нужно долго искать инфу как это делать, может есть либа.

Comment: Возможно при использовании localhost механизм бития tcp пакетов не срабатывает, и он закачивает всё в память, если памяти не хватает подкачивает дисковую.

Answer (score 0):

Как уточнили в комментарии, то что при загрузке большого файла, весь файл загружается целиком в оперативную память. Чтобы такого не происходило надо передавать файл частями, в данном случае можно использовать буфер, вот пример:

```
if (Files.exists(Path.of(HttpServer.directory+path)) && ! Files.isDirectory(Path.of(HttpServer.directory+path))) {
    File f = new File(HttpServer.directory+path);
    long contentLength = f.length();
    String contentType = Files.probeContentType(f.toPath());
    String header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-type: " + contentType + "\nContent-Length: " + contentLength + "\nConnection: close\n\n";
    out.write(header.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    try (InputStream fileContent = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f))) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = fileContent.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    out.flush();}
```

Размер буфера выбираем в зависимости от настроенного приема на HTTP сервере.